# mysql command not found after pipe

Tags: terminal, mysql

I installed mysql with homebrew.

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

and

```
which mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

but when I try to use it after a pipe, I get the following error

```
unzip -p dump.sql.zip | mysql
zsh: command not found:  mysql
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the error?  Secondly, `mysql` takes several arguments like user, password (where applicable), database, etc.  You seem to be missing a number of those.

Comment: Please add the error message you get so the question can be reopened.

Comment: I added the error message, it was in the question title already before.
No need to add `mysql` arguments, as when `mysql` is recognized, it will report another error.

Comment: Details are important. If there really are two spaces between `found:` and `mysql` in the error message you still had shift/opt/whatever pressed from typing the pipe character when you pressed space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra character before `mysql` that looks like a space, but is not a space. You have to fix that before running the command. This problem occurs when you press the space bar while you are holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key.

```
$ # Option + Space
$ unzip -p dump.sql.zip | mysql
zsh: command not found:  mysql
$ # Regular Space
$ unzip -p dump.sql.zip | mysql
...
expected output
...
```

Another example:

```
$ # Option + Space
$ echo "hi" | less
-bash:  less: command not found
$ # Regular Space
$ echo "hi" | less

hi
(END)
```

Another option is to eliminate the space after the pipe entirely:

```
$ echo "hi" |less

hi
(END)
```

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> = \xc2\xa0 (UTF-8)

<kbd>Space</kbd> = Regular Space

Comment: While typing `|mysql` solves the problem it might be better to get used to relasing shift/opt/whatever after typing the pipe and before typing the space character.

Comment: Does that make a character that looks like a space?

Comment: A real extra space doesn't explain the error message, running `cmd1 | cmd2` is perfectly valid shell syntax. And yes, depending on keyboard settings and locale it does.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the extra space given after the ":" in the first error message.  This is because of using the "option space" character instead of a normal space.  Your output is similar t the first of these two

[[image: Option Space before first missing command in pipe[1]]